# Difference between "even if" and "even though"

Tags: difference, conditional-constructions, conjunctions

When I was at university, my English teacher used to insist a lot on the difference between these two expressions, telling us that *even if* was to be used when introducing a hypothetical situation (*Even if* I knew where John is, I wouldn't tell you), whereas *even though* was to be used as a concession or admission (*Even though* I know where John is, I won't tell you).

A few years have passed since my university days, and I'm under the impression that this kind of distinction is no longer made. *Even if* seems to be prevailing, and *even though* is less frequently found either in texts or in speech. Is my feeling correct? Has the difference between the two forms been cancelled?

Comment: Your feeling is not correct. Have you tried substituting *even if* into *even though I know ... I wouldn't tell you*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what your English teacher told you is right, as far as it goes; but there is a middle ground it does not address, where either may be used. I imagine that very often this is what you are hearing.

The *even* clause may be neither hypothetical nor concessive but 'occasional'—that is, it may refer to a condition which is sometimes true and sometimes not. In such a case you might use *even if* or *even though*, because both are contextually equivalent to *even when*:

> You should eat breakfast every morning, even if/though/when you're hung over.
>   Even if/though/when he's sometimes over my head, I enjoy Prof. Sartorius' lectures.

In formal contexts you would probably adjust these sentences a little to fit the conjunction more precisely:

> ... even though you may be hung over
>   Even when he's over my head ...

But those are niceties which are not required in ordinary conversation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the difference has been cancelled or the meaning of those expressions has changed: from a cursory search, both still hold their meaning (*even if* = *whether or not* - but not always, note a comment below / *even though* = *despite*).

Comment: It should be noted that "even if" and "whether or not" can be used quite differently. Examples of the difference: "Even if I knew where John is, I wouldn't tell you." and "Whether of not I know where John is doesn't change the fact that I wouldn't tell you."

Comment: *Even if I knew where John was ...*, surely?

Comment: *Even if I had known where John was, I wouldn't have told you.*

Answer (score 1):

The Touchstone series English book, Level 3, that I have explains the two this way.

1. "Even though" is similar to "but" or "despite the fact"; therefore, when using this term in a sentence one should be able to substitute the phrase "even though" for one of the alternate words, which means you may have to change the sentence structure. Example: "I know you don't like musicals but you may enjoy this one". The word "but" was substituted for "even though" (Even though I don't usually like musicals, I loved this one.)
2. "Even if" means "whether or not". Example: "Even if you don't like musicals, you might enjoy this one." OR, "Whether or not you like musicals, you might enjoy this one."

Comment: Is this a direct quote? If so, you should add blockquote formatting.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge it is still used this way exclusively. I have not heard it used anyway other then this, nor can I find a reference to such usage.

Comment: I cannot quote anything specific, but I'm sure I've read sentences like "*Even if* I don't like it, I normally go to the cinema every Saturday night." According to my teacher and you, this is wrong and the sentence should be amended into "*Even though* I don't like it".

Comment: That usually used in a rhetorical sense, as in "even if I hate you, I won't kill you" where it implies obvious hatred.